# Reducing Image Size and Saving it in MySQL DB with Java

Tags: java

I know that we can save image in mysql using BLOB Data Type and The Code i have used it as follows,

```
    JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
    fc.setFileFilter(new JPEGImageFileFilter());
    int res = fc.showOpenDialog(null);
    try {
        if (res == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {

           File image = new File(fc.getSelectedFile().getPath());
           FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream ( image );
           String sql="insert into imgtst (username,image) values (?, ?)";
           pst=con.prepareStatement(sql);
           pst.setString(1, user);
           pst.setBinaryStream (2, fis, (int) file.length() );

        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "you must select image",
                    "Abortin", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
        }
    } catch (Exception ioException) {
             e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Now What do i need to make sure the file size which is saving into the  database should not be more than 100 KB if its more than that size i need some method to compress the size of an image to be 100 KB.Kindly give your valuable suggestions.

Comment: why don't you save images in a folder and save path 2 database

Comment: http://www.javalobby.org/articles/ultimate-image/#11

Comment: Because the image is compressed in some way, the actual byte size the image will end up as is difficult to determine as the compression takes into many different variables within the image...

Comment: Compressing an image (unless it's a BMP) will not generally do much to the size. Option 1: don't save it in the database but on the file system with a link in the database. Option 2: rescale the image but then you will lose the original and it is hard to pinpoint which size you need to attain that 100 kb limit.

Comment: thanks for the reply @getlost.yeah thats a good idea to store image path only but i need to add import and export db functionality to my application in that case i can't expect the user of application to make sure that the folder which contatins picture always be protected(he/she should not delete it to work).

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
public static BufferedImage resizeImage(Image image, int width, int height) {
        final BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        final Graphics2D graphics2D = bufferedImage.createGraphics();
        graphics2D.setComposite(AlphaComposite.Src);
        graphics2D.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION,RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
        graphics2D.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING,RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
        graphics2D.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        graphics2D.drawImage(image, 0, 0, width, height, null);
        graphics2D.dispose();
        return bufferedImage;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try compress the image first before insert it into database.
this is the example i got for compressing the image :

```
File imageFile = new File("myimage.jpg");
        File compressedImageFile = new File("myimage_compressed.jpg");

        InputStream is = new FileInputStream(imageFile);
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(compressedImageFile);

        float quality = 0.5f;

        // create a BufferedImage as the result of decoding the supplied InputStream
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(is);

        // get all image writers for JPG format
        Iterator<ImageWriter> writers = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("jpg");

        if (!writers.hasNext())
            throw new IllegalStateException("No writers found");

        ImageWriter writer = (ImageWriter) writers.next();
        ImageOutputStream ios = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(os);
        writer.setOutput(ios);

        ImageWriteParam param = writer.getDefaultWriteParam();

        // compress to a given quality
        param.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT);
        param.setCompressionQuality(quality);

        // appends a complete image stream containing a single image and
        //associated stream and image metadata and thumbnails to the output
        writer.write(null, new IIOImage(image, null, null), param);

        // close all streams
        is.close();
        os.close();
        ios.close();
        writer.dispose();
```

Comment: i got it from this link http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/desktop-java/imageio/compress-a-jpeg-file/